# How pass value into service class from broadcast class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

**SimpleSmsReciever.java**

```
public class SimpleSmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    // Start Application's  Service
    Intent startemailsms=new Intent(context,EmailSms.class);    startemailsms.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   startemailsms.putExtra("numbermsg", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
    startemailsms.putExtra("bodymsg", messages.getMessageBody());
    context.startService(startemailsms);
    }
}
```

**EmailSms.java**

```
public class EmailSms extends Service{
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
         String bodysms=bodymsg;
         String numbersms=numbermsg;
         SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, "my.email@gmail.com",numbersms,bodysms);
         sm.execute();
    }
    return 0;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent p1) {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return null;
}
```

but unknow **getIntent** into EmailSms.java Service..dont passing value..

Comment: The Intent is the one received as argument on onStartCommand, you already got it with: ```Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();```

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos yes sry i was wrong peast cod...edit now but again error getIntent Extera and Unknow...u can edit this class for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Intent instance you received as argument at `onStartCommand` it should be:

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { //argument to receive
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); //using argument
    // Rest as is
```